# ¿Cómo puedo obtener la suma y el mes y separar los resultados de dos tablas diferentes en SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo mis dos tablas con sus 2 columnas y lo que deseo obtener es la suma separada del total de la tabla ploteo y por separado el total de la tabla servicio técnico, así mismo obtener el número de mes de ploteo y servicio técnico, pero por separado.

**Tablas base de datos**

```
|*ot_ploteo*   |                             |*ot_servicio_tecnico*  |
|--------------|                             |-----------------------|
|Total_OTPloteo|                             |Total_OTServicioTecnico|    
|Fecha_OTPloteo|                             |Fecha_OTServicioTecnico|
```

**Estos son los datos almacenados en cada una de ellas**

```
|Total_OTPloteo|Fecha_OTPloteo|          |Total_OTServicioTecnico|Fecha_OTServicioTecnico|
|7.00          |2021-02-07    |          |44.00                  | 2021-02-06            |
                                         |12.00                  | 2021-02-05            |
```

**Lo que deseo obtener es lo siguiente**

```
|totalPloteo|mesPloteo|totalSt|mesSt|
|7.00       |2        |56.00  |2    |
```

**Mi código de prueba no funcional**

```
SELECT MONTH
    ( Fecha_OTServicioTecnico ) AS mes,
    SUM( Total_OTServicioTecnico ) AS monto,
    MONTH ( Fecha_OTPloteo ) AS mesPloteo,
    SUM( Total_OTPloteo ) AS montoPloteo 
FROM
    `ot_servicio_tecnico`,
    `ot_ploteo` 
WHERE
    `Fecha_OTServicioTecnico` >= '2021-01-01' 
    AND `Fecha_OTServicioTecnico` <= '2021-12-31' AND `Fecha_OTPloteo` >= '2021-01-01' 
    AND `Fecha_OTPloteo` <= '2021-12-31' 
    AND `Estado_OTServicioTecnico` = 1 
    AND `Estado_OTPloteo` = 1 
GROUP BY
    `mes`
```

Del código que tengo funcionan bien estos resultados que espero obtener o al menos en primera instancia **mesPloteo**, **totalSt**, **mesSt**, pero del **totalPloteo** es como que se volviera a sumar otra vez 7.00 o se multiplicara pero el resultado que me sale es 14.00 y no solo 7.00.

Comment: Y donde estas uniendo las dos tablas? porque solo estas haciendo un full join, y necesitas un inner join...

Comment: Lo que pasa es que son tablas separadas donde no comparten nada en común, solo las uno para que en una sola consulta me devuelva la suma total de la tabla ploteo y la suma total de la tabla servicio técnico pero por separado en una sola consulta, pero si estoy mal y debo usar inner join corrigeme por favor.

Comment: Si, comparten algo.. que las dos deben devolver una sola fila ;) por lo tanto, tu query no es a las tablas.. es a los resultados que devuelven las consultas a cada tabla ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que indicas que deseas obtener, tengo la sensación de que buscas algo así:

```
SELECT anualidad,mes,totalPloteo,totalSt FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(Fecha_OTPloteo) anualidad,
      MONTH(Fecha_OTPloteo) mes,
      SUM(Total_OTPloteo) totalPloteo
      FROM ot_ploteo
      GROUP BY 1,2
  ) c1 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT YEAR(Fecha_OTServicioTecnico) anualidad,
      MONTH(Fecha_OTServicioTecnico) mes,
      SUM(Total_OTServicioTecnico) totalSt
      FROM ot_servicio_tecnico
      GROUP BY 1,2 
  ) c2 USING(mes,anualidad)
UNION
SELECT anualidad,mes,totalPloteo,totalSt FROM (
    SELECT YEAR(Fecha_OTPloteo) anualidad,
      MONTH(Fecha_OTPloteo) mes,
      SUM(Total_OTPloteo) totalPloteo
      FROM ot_ploteo
      GROUP BY 1,2  
  ) c1 RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT YEAR(Fecha_OTServicioTecnico) anualidad,
      MONTH(Fecha_OTServicioTecnico) mes,
      SUM(Total_OTServicioTecnico) totalSt
      FROM ot_servicio_tecnico
      GROUP BY 1,2
  ) c2 USING(mes,anualidad);
```

Para obtener:

```
+-----------+------+-------------+---------+
| anualidad | mes  | totalPloteo | totalSt |
+-----------+------+-------------+---------+
|      2021 |    2 |           7 |      56 |
+-----------+------+-------------+---------+
```

Así conectas ambos resultados intermedios por el dato que tienen en común, que es el mes.

Te facilito el dataset para las comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE ot_ploteo(
  Total_OTPloteo float,
  Fecha_OTPloteo date
  );
CREATE TABLE ot_servicio_tecnico(
  Total_OTServicioTecnico float,
  Fecha_OTServicioTecnico date
  );
INSERT INTO ot_ploteo (Total_OTPloteo, Fecha_OTPloteo) VALUES
  (7,'2021-02-07');
INSERT INTO ot_servicio_tecnico (
  Total_OTServicioTecnico, Fecha_OTServicioTecnico
 ) VALUES
  (44,'2021-02-06'),
  (12,'2021-02-05');
```

Comment: Funciona perfecto, pero, cuando ingreso un dato diferente con un mes diferente, por ejemplo enero, sigue consultando en este caso como si tuviera los 2 en el mes febrero, es por eso que el mesPloteo y el mes, los necesitaba por separado, porque al hacer mi gráfica estadística me es más fácil.

Comment: Eso es por el JOIN, usa un LEFT JOIN o registra un dato ese mismo mes en la otra tabla

Comment: Gracias compa, funcionó correctamente

Comment: Compa una cosita, en caso de que en ploteo si haya datos, pero en servicio tecnico no hay ninguno, en la consulta no me muestra ningun dato, esto aplicando el left join, si quiero que me salga tengo que ocupar el right join, como puedo hacer para no tener que hacer este cambio ya que esta consulta la aplico en una grafica, ayuda porfa

Comment: Sabía que este momento llegaría :) Lo que estás buscando en un `FULL JOIN` que es el `UNION` de un `LEFT JOIN` con un `RIGHT JOIN` y, lamentablemente MySQL no lo tiene implementado. Tienes que hacerlo manualmente. Te modifico la respuesta para que veas cómo

Comment: Muchas gracias compa jejeje es exactamente lo que necesitaba.

Comment: Compa y en caso de querer buscar los meses, pero por año???, lo intenté añadiendo un where en cada select, pero no me salen los resultados, ayúdame porfa como podría utilizar el where con fecha.

Comment: Es cuestión de agrupar, te modifico la respuesta

Comment: Creo que no me hice entender bien jejeje lo que espero de la consulta es que pueda aplicar un where entre un rango de fechas, el mes, el totalSt y el totalPloteo es la respuesta que busco pero de esa respuesta necesito que en la consulta busque por fechas por ejemplo qué salga el mes, el totalSt y el totalPloteo del 1 de enero de 2021 al 14 de febrero de 2021, intenté con los where en cada select pero no me funcionó esa condición 

Comment: Publica una nueva pregunta con lo que has intentado y, para los datos de ejemplo, qué pretendías obtener.

Comment: Listo compa te comparto el link de la pregunta por favor

https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/427773/c%c3%b3mo-puedo-obtener-en-sql-el-mes-en-una-sola-columna-y-el-total-en-dos-columnas