# ¿Cómo puedo obtener en SQL el mes en una sola columna y el total en dos columnas diferentes entre dos tablas y entre rangos de fechas?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Tengo mis dos tablas las cuales tienen su total y su fecha en cada tabla, lo que deseo obtener es el mes en una sola columna de ambas tablas, pero si el mes es diferente la una de la otra se muestren los valores en las filas respectivas, adjunto mis tablas, y el resultado que deseo obtener con mi propuesta fallida.

**Estas son mis dos tablas**

### Tabla Ploteo

```
+---------------+----------------+
| Fecha_OTPloteo| Total_OTPloteo |
+---------------+----------------+
| 7.00          |  2021-02-07    |
+---------------+----------------+
```

### Tabla Servicio Técnico

```
+------------------------+------------------------+
| Fecha_OTServicioTecnico| Total_OTServicioTecnico|
+------------------------+------------------------+
| 160.00                 |  2021-02-14            |
+------------------------+------------------------+
```

### El resultado que espero obtener es el siguiente

Si los **meses** son iguales se muestran en una sola columna:

```
+------+-------------+---------+
| mes  | totalPloteo | totalSt |
+------+-------------+---------+
|    2 |        7.00 | 160.00  |
+------+-------------+---------+
```

Pero si los **meses** son distintos y el total no representa dicho mes se deberían mostrar los siguientes resultados:

```
+------+-------------+---------+
| mes  | totalPloteo | totalSt |
+------+-------------+---------+
|    2 |        7.00 |   null  |
+------+-------------+---------+
|    3 |        null | 160.00  |
+------+-------------+---------+
```

Todos esos resultados los espero obtener mediante un rango de fecha, si la fecha es mayor a... y menor a... me muestren los valores de arriba. Tengo el siguiente código donde al hacer los where respectivos, simplemente no me muestran los valores.

### Revision de código

```
    SELECT mes, totalPloteo, totalSt
FROM (
         SELECT MONTH(Fecha_OTPloteo) mes,
                SUM(Total_OTPloteo)   totalPloteo
         FROM ot_ploteo
         WHERE Fecha_OTPloteo >= 2021 - 01 - 01
           AND Fecha_OTPloteo <= 2021 - 12 - 31
         GROUP BY 1
     ) c1
         LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT MONTH(Fecha_OTServicioTecnico) mes,
           SUM(Total_OTServicioTecnico)   totalSt
    FROM ot_servicio_tecnico
    WHERE Fecha_OTServicioTecnico >= 2021 - 01 - 01
      AND Fecha_OTServicioTecnico <= 2021 - 12 - 31
    GROUP BY 1
) c2 USING (mes)
UNION
SELECT mes, totalPloteo, totalSt
FROM (
         SELECT MONTH(Fecha_OTPloteo) mes,
                SUM(Total_OTPloteo)   totalPloteo
         FROM ot_ploteo
         WHERE Fecha_OTPloteo >= 2021 - 01 - 01
           AND Fecha_OTPloteo <= 2021 - 12 - 31
         GROUP BY 1
     ) c1
         RIGHT JOIN (
    SELECT MONTH(Fecha_OTServicioTecnico) mes,
           SUM(Total_OTServicioTecnico)   totalSt
    FROM ot_servicio_tecnico
    WHERE Fecha_OTServicioTecnico >= 2021 - 01 - 01
      AND Fecha_OTServicioTecnico <= 2021 - 12 - 31
    GROUP BY 1
) c2 USING (mes);
```

Comment: En Sql Server existe el Full Join, en MySql es necesario simularlo.

Comment: ¿que versión de MySQL amigo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Me da la sensación de que el problema lo tienes con el formato de las fechas. Por favor, prueba así:

```
SELECT mes, totalPloteo, totalSt
  FROM (
      SELECT MONTH(Fecha_OTPloteo) mes,
        SUM(Total_OTPloteo) totalPloteo
      FROM ot_ploteo
      WHERE Fecha_OTPloteo BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 LEFT JOIN (
      SELECT MONTH(Fecha_OTServicioTecnico) mes,
        SUM(Total_OTServicioTecnico) totalSt
      FROM ot_servicio_tecnico
      WHERE Fecha_OTServicioTecnico BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c2 USING (mes)
UNION
SELECT mes, totalPloteo, totalSt
  FROM (
      SELECT MONTH(Fecha_OTPloteo) mes,
        SUM(Total_OTPloteo)   totalPloteo
      FROM ot_ploteo
      WHERE Fecha_OTPloteo BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c1 RIGHT JOIN (
      SELECT MONTH(Fecha_OTServicioTecnico) mes,
        SUM(Total_OTServicioTecnico)   totalSt
      FROM ot_servicio_tecnico
      WHERE Fecha_OTServicioTecnico BETWEEN '2021-01-01' AND '2021-12-31'
      GROUP BY 1
  ) c2 USING (mes);
```

Para este dataset:

```
CREATE TABLE ot_ploteo(
  Total_OTPloteo float,
  Fecha_OTPloteo date
  );
CREATE TABLE ot_servicio_tecnico(
  Total_OTServicioTecnico float,
  Fecha_OTServicioTecnico date
  );
INSERT INTO ot_ploteo (Total_OTPloteo, Fecha_OTPloteo) VALUES
  (7,'2021-02-07');
INSERT INTO ot_servicio_tecnico (
  Total_OTServicioTecnico, Fecha_OTServicioTecnico
 ) VALUES
  (44,'2020-02-06'),
  (160,'2021-03-05');
```

Obtengo este restulado:

```
+------+-------------+---------+
| mes  | totalPloteo | totalSt |
+------+-------------+---------+
|    2 |           7 |    NULL |
|    3 |        NULL |     160 |
+------+-------------+---------+
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, tu respuesta me funcionó perfectamente

Answer (score 3):

**Saludos y buen día.**

He preparado lo siguiente; solo revisa que la versiòn de MySQL que usas soporte `WITH` o en su defecto *te indico* en lo mismo que realizar.

Básicamente es:

1. Obtener todas las fechas y de cada mes incluido obtener su inicio y fin.
2. Generar un `agrupador` el cual será la forma en que lo agrupas (yo aquí uso **año** y **mes** aunque tu indicas solo **mes**).
3. Realizar las sumatorias de cada tabla mediante los rangos generados colocando solo el agrupador y el resultado de cada sumatoria.

```
WITH FechasInicio AS
(
    /* Obtenemos todos los dìas de inicio de cada mes sin repetirlo */
    SELECT DISTINCT(AllUnicos.Fecha_Inicio) FROM
    (
        /* Cada mes lo convertimos a dìa primero */
        SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_OTPloteo,'%Y-%m-01'),'%Y-%m-%d') AS Fecha_Inicio FROM Ploteo
        UNION
        SELECT STR_TO_DATE(DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_OTServicioTecnico,'%Y-%m-01'),'%Y-%m-%d') AS Fecha_Inicio FROM Servicio_Tecnico
    )
    AllUnicos
    ORDER BY AllUnicos.Fecha_Inicio

),
RangosFechas AS
(
    /* Generamos con las fechas inicios el fin de cada mes y su agrupador */
    SELECT 
        Fecha_Inicio, 
        LAST_DAY(Fecha_Inicio) Fecha_Fin,
        DATE_FORMAT(Fecha_Inicio,'%Y-%d') Agrupador
    FROM
        FechasInicio
        
    /* NOTA: 
            *   Agrupador es el "mes en una sola columna" que refieres en tu enunciado; sin embargo aquì, lo pongo con año y mes; 
                cuestiòn realices aquì el ajuste si solo te interesa mes pero no el año.
    */
)

/* Ahora agregamos las sumatorias */
SELECT 
    RAIZ.Agrupador,
    SUM(Plt.Total_OTPloteo) Total_OTPloteo,
    SUM(SrvTect.Total_OTServicioTecnico) Total_OTServicioTecnico
    
FROM
    RangosFechas RAIZ
LEFT JOIN Ploteo Plt ON Plt.Fecha_OTPloteo BETWEEN RAIZ.Fecha_Inicio AND RAIZ.Fecha_Fin
                                                    -- A continuación las fechas intervalos que deberás/necesitas establecer/cambiar
                                                    AND Plt.Fecha_OTPloteo  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2021-02-01','%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2021-02-07','%Y-%m-%d')
LEFT JOIN Servicio_Tecnico SrvTect ON SrvTect.Fecha_OTServicioTecnico BETWEEN RAIZ.Fecha_Inicio AND RAIZ.Fecha_Fin
                                                    -- A continuación las fechas intervalos que deberás/necesitas establecer/cambiar
                                                    AND SrvTect.Fecha_OTServicioTecnico  BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('2021-02-01','%Y-%m-%d') AND STR_TO_DATE('2021-02-07','%Y-%m-%d')
GROUP BY RAIZ.Agrupador
;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero en caso de hacer ya la consulta, me agrupa las fechas, pero en caso de los totales no me muestra la información, edité tu solución con el nombre de mis tablas para ejecutar la consulta, pero no me muestra los totales.